# Tilemill tooltip href link missing when uploaded to mapbox

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

In Tilemill this tooltip functions (href opens the link in the same window when in the Tilemill program), but when uploaded to mapbox the field after "More info:" is blank although the other fields in the tooltip work.

This is what I have in the Tilemill "Templates" section "Full" field:

```
Site: {{{PROJECT_NA}}}<br/>
Location: {{{ADDRESS}}}<br/>
Potential Contaminant: {{{potentia_2}}}<br/>
Size: {{{ACRES}}} Acres<br/>
More info: <a href="http://www.envirostor.dtsc.ca.gov/public/profile_report.asp?global_id={{{ENVIROSTOR}}}" target="_blank”>visit Envirostor</a>
```

I would also like this link to open in a new window. Sorry for asking two questions.

Answer (score 1):

If this is verbatim, it looks like you've got an HTML problem: `target="_blank”` - the second " here is a curly ”, which is invalid.